# How can I get rid of dots in front of relative module path?

Tags: typescript, path, declaration, relative-path

In a typescript project how can I get rid of dots in front of the module path?

I tried defining a declaration file and importing it like how we import external  packages but it complains with `Cannot find module 'module-name'`.

When exporting all modules from one file and using that file, I still need to import the relative path of that file which i don't like.

For example in my test suite I have:

```
import { Injector } from '../../../../src/lib/injector';
import { APIRequestManager } from '../../../../src/lib/request-manager';
import { DatabasePopulator } from '../../../../src/lib/database-populator';
import { DatabaseManager } from '../../../../src/lib/database-manager';

const databasePopulator = Injector.request<DatabasePopulator> ('DatabasePopulator');
const apiRequest = Injector.request<APIRequestManager>('APIRequestManager');
const databaseManager = Injector.request<DatabaseManager>('DatabaseManager');
```

So one solution is to export all libraries from one file:

src/exporter.ts

```
export * from './lib/database-manager';
export * from './lib/database-populator';
export * from './lib/injector';
export * from './lib/request-manager';
```

Which I still need to import with trailing dots in the path:

```
import * as testHelpers from '../../../../src/exporter';

const databasePopulator = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.DatabasePopulator>('DatabasePopulator');
const apiRequest = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.APIRequestManager>('APIRequestManager');
const databaseManager = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.DatabaseManager>('DatabaseManager');
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import * as testHelpers from 'testFramework';
const databasePopulator = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.DatabasePopulator>('DatabasePopulator');
const apiRequest = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.APIRequestManager>('APIRequestManager');
const databaseManager = testHelpers.Injector.request<testHelpers.DatabaseManager>('DatabaseManager');
```

Comment: could you give us a code example of your issue? It would help people understand the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: Updates with examples hope it makes more sense now
Thanks!

Comment: The exporter pattern is to go.. also trying to refactor you code in such a way that your components are shallower.